# Extract two files from tar.gz file into memory

Tags: java, android, gzip

I have GZIP archive with two files inside of it packed with tar utility. I need to extract both of them into memory. So I need to get two `byte` arrays as a result. But all the examples of `GZIPInputStream` usage simply read bytes and save them to the output stream so I have no idea how to get two `byte[]` arrays as result.

Comment: "I have GZIP archive with two files inside of it." GZIP doesn't work like that. It doesn't have the concept of multiple files. It's just compressed data.

Comment: So do you mean you've effectively got a tar.gz file, or a tgz file? If so, you need to separate out the gzip part of extraction from the tar part. When you decompress the gzip file, you'll get a tar file, and you can then get the two files from that.

Comment: @JonSkeet tar.gz. Any examples of working with .tar files? Notice that I don't want to create any temp files. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't used any tar libraries myself - see https://code.google.com/p/jtar/ though.

Answer (score 0):

[libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/) should do what you need.  Here is an excerpt from their home page describing what it is:

> ## libarchive
>
> ***Multi-format archive and compression library***
>   
>   
>   The source distribution includes the libarchive library, the bsdtar and bsdcpio command-line programs, full test suite, and documentation:
>   
>   
>   Stable release: [libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz](http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-3.1.2.tar.gz) [libarchive-3.1.2.zip](http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-3.1.2.zip) (since Jan 13, 2013)
>   
>   Legacy release: [libarchive-2.8.5.zip](http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-2.8.5.zip) (since Sept 3, 2011)
>   
>   
>   The libarchive library features:
>
> - Support for a variety of archive and compression formats.
> - Robust automatic format detection, including archive/compression combinations such as tar.gz.
> - Zero-copy internal architecture for high performance.
> - Streaming architecture eliminates all limits on size of archive, limits on entry sizes depend on particular formats.
> - Carefully factored code to minimize bloat when programs are statically linked.
> - Growing test suite to verify correctness of new ports.
> - Works on most POSIX-like systems (including FreeBSD, Linux, Solaris, etc.)
> - Supports Windows, including Cygwin, MinGW, and Visual Studio.
>
> The `bsdtar` and `bscpio` command-line utilities are feature- and performance-competitive with other tar and cpio implementations:
>
> - Reads a variety of formats, including tar, pax, cpio, zip, xar, lha, ar, cab, mtree, rar, and ISO images.
> - Writes tar, pax, cpio, zip, xar, ar, ISO, mtree, and shar archives.
> - Automatically handles archives compressed with gzip, bzip2, lzip, xz, lzma, or compress.
> - Unique format conversion feature.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: If I provide "essential parts" on _how_ to use libarchive, and the link disappears, then those essential parts have _also_ become useless.  I understand the volatility of links, but I don't see how to improve the answer in the event the link disappears.

Comment: That's simply not true.  Links can change.  A broken link doesn't signify that the product no longer exists or becomes useless.  Don't worry, I went ahead and edited your answer adding in all of the essential parts from their home page to explain to future visitors what libarchive is.